# How to set the timestamp if there's a part in the String missing?

Tags: java, string, datetime, jakarta-ee, timestamp

For example you have:

```
String datetime = new String("2008-05-09");

Timestamp.valueOf( datetime )
```

The value will be: `2008-05-09 00:00:00.0` without any exception.

Another example:

```
String datetime = new String("2008-05-09 13:34");
Timestamp.valueOf( datetime )
```

The value will be: `2008-05-09 13:34:00.0` without any exception.

Thanks,

Comment: I do not see any question mark `?` in your post body. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you are going to get a string that is only part of a timestamp and you want to parse it? You can use SimpleDateFormat if you know the format you will receive. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to convert `Strings` into `timestamp` objects regardless of whether they contain time part or not.

You can do it by this way: String -> Date -> TimeStamp

To convert String into `Date`, you can use `DateUtils` library (with multiple date formats) and then, you can convert date into timestamp. Have a look at the below example:

```
String[] dateFormats = new String[]{"yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"};

for(String dateString : new String[]{"2008-05-09", "2008-05-09 13:34", "2008-05-09 13:34:40"}){
    Date date = DateUtils.parseDate(dateString, dateFormats);
    Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    System.out.println(timeStamp);
}
```